# place subtitle beside centered heading title

Tags: html, css, typography

https://i.stack.imgur.com/giiPr.jpg

I'm trying to achieve the typography above. The title is centered, but the subtitle is just beside the title. i was only able to achieve something similar below with boostrap's small class.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/bTyYJ.jpg

The problem is, the subtitle is making space to be included in the center. is this possible? I know I can position absolute the sub-text, and position it properly, but I have a bunch of pages that my client want it to be like that.

Any ideas?

Here's the code 've used by the way:

```css
.small{
 text-transform: lowercase !important;
 font-style: italic !important;
 font-family: times, serif !important;
}
.blue{
 color: #35C4F0 !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<h1 class="text-center text-uppercase"><span class="small blue">software </span>game <br/>development</h1>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hello brother may be this will help you thanks

```
<div class="head-box">

<h1 class="text-center text-uppercase"><span class="small blue">software </span>game <br/>development</h1>
</div>
```

and here is css

```
.head-box{float: left; width: 100%; position: relative;}
.small{
text-transform: lowercase !important;
font-style: italic !important;
font-family: times, serif !important;
}
.blue{
color: #35C4F0 !important;
position: absolute;
 left:25%;
 top:30px;
transform: translate(-25%, 0);
}
```

and here is [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uopx4hh2/)

Comment: works pretty good on mobile. But not exactly what I'm looking for on other screen sizes.

Comment: on which screen size you are testing brother

Comment: Tnx bradah. Yeah, I was actually thinking of just doing it this way. But I think I might have problems when I have different character lengths with the other pages I will be working with. But soo far, this is the best answer.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this. I have added below css and `div` to wrap `h1` tag.

```
.title h1 {
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: left;
}
```

```css
.small{
  text-transform: lowercase !important;
  font-style: italic !important;
  font-family: times, serif !important;
}
.blue{
  color: #35C4F0 !important;
}
.title h1 {
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: left;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="text-center title">
  <h1 class="text-uppercase"><span class="small blue">software </span>game <br/>development</h1>
</div>
```

Comment: it only works on that one since because of the length of the subtext. But it really does not work on other one's where the subtitle and title are a little longer. :(

Comment: Can you provide any screenshot...?

Comment: This is work. why you say it's not work..? and In which title have you an issue...? can you give it..?

Comment: I did said it works on that one(title/subtitle) that I gave. But when i try it on other pages, where the title and subtitle are longer, it just does not work. try changing the title from "game <br/>development" to "software <br/>development" and the subtitle from "software" to "remote" on your snippet soo you would see for yourself.

Answer (score 0):

```
.blue{
  color: #35C4F0;
  text-transform: lowercase;
  font-style: italic;
  letter-spacing: 3.5px;
}

h1{
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-align: center;
}

<h1 class=""><span class="small blue">software </span>game<br/>development</h1>
```